# MySQL: Stored Procedure Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I am writing a stored procedure in phpmyadmin but I am getting a syntax error near `Update` statement. But if I put my update statement inside my if statement than all errors been resolved.

Q: Why update statement outside causes an error?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tbl_people_update`(IN `p_Id` INT, IN `p_Name` VARCHAR(150), IN `p_Mobile_Number` VARCHAR(100))
    IF CHAR_LENGTH(p_Mobile_Number) <= 0 THEN
     SET p_Mobile_Number = '12345';
    END IF;

    UPDATE tbl_people
     SET 
     Name=p_Name,
     Mobile_Number = p_Mobile_Number
     WHERE
     Id=p_Id;
```

The error is as follows:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE tbl_people SET Name=p_Name, Mobile_Number =
>   p_Mobile_Number WHER' at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tbl_people_update`(IN `p_Id` INT, IN `p_Name` VARCHAR(150), IN `p_Mobile_Number` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
     IF CHAR_LENGTH(p_Mobile_Number) <= 0 THEN
     SET p_Mobile_Number = '12345';
    END IF;
    UPDATE tbl_people
     SET 
     Name=p_Name,
     Mobile_Number = p_Mobile_Number
     WHERE
     Id=p_Id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten re-define delimiter, try this:

```
delimiter ||
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tbl_people_update`(IN `p_Id` INT, IN `p_Name` VARCHAR(150), IN `p_Mobile_Number` VARCHAR(100))
    IF CHAR_LENGTH(p_Mobile_Number) <= 0 THEN
     SET p_Mobile_Number = '12345';
    END IF;

    UPDATE tbl_people
     SET 
     Name=p_Name,
     Mobile_Number = p_Mobile_Number
     WHERE
     Id=p_Id;
||
delimiter ;
```